# Set input of type number to string

Tags: javascript, html

I am building my own context menu and am replacing copy / cut / paste functionality. I have copy and paste working but I cannot paste arbitrary text into an input of type 'number'.

I am setting the value using javascript similiar to below

```
document.getElementById('input').value = 'some text';
```

Whenever type is of number, the text is lost and the input is left blank.

Can I set the input to a string? The system paste allows this, but the input seems to parse the input and fail.

[Obligatory jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j8Lw7to/)

Comment: So, set the input type to text otherwise there's no any idea...

Comment: Yeah why have the input as number? To me it makes more sense as `text` since you can also place numbers into that. If there is more too this or a reason why you need `number` let me know.

Comment: An input of type 'number' only allows numeric input. If your string happens to parse as a valid number, then the paste will work fine, but you simply can't put a text value in a number field.

Answer (score 2):

You can change

```
<input id="input" type="number" value="1"></input>
```

to

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="1"></input>
```

Or change it in your javascript by adding

```
document.getElementById('input').setAttribute('type','text')
```

in your `setText()` function

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j8Lw7to/1/)**: Here is the resulting jsFiddle